# Error installing Luximono font through getnonfreefonts on Mactex

Tags: fonts, packages, texlive, mactex

Having installed getnonfreefonts, trying `sudo getnonfreefonts --sys luximono` gives me either one of the following errors:

```
curl: (55) getpeername() failed with errno 22: Invalid argument
curl: (7) Failed to connect to mirrors.ctan.org port 80: Operation timed out
```

Using `sudo getnonfreefonts --sys vntex-nonfree`installs VnTex without problem, but all other fonts do not work.

Running the command with `--debug` gives me this:

```
DEBUG: getnonfreefonts rev. 2017-06-02.
DEBUG: argv[0]: '/usr/local/bin/getnonfreefonts'
DEBUG: argv[1]: '--sys'
DEBUG: argv[2]: '--debug'
DEBUG: argv[3]: 'luximono'
DEBUG: opt_sys=1
DEBUG: opt_user=0
DEBUG: PATH[0]: '/opt/local/bin'.
DEBUG: PATH[1]: '/opt/local/sbin'.
DEBUG: PATH[2]: '/opt/local/bin'.
DEBUG: PATH[3]: '/opt/local/sbin'.
DEBUG: PATH[4]: '/usr/local/bin'.
DEBUG: PATH[5]: '/usr/bin'.
DEBUG: PATH[6]: '/bin'.
DEBUG: PATH[7]: '/usr/sbin'.
DEBUG: PATH[8]: '/sbin'.
DEBUG: PATH[9]: '/Library/TeX/texbin'.
DEBUG: PATH[10]: '/opt/X11/bin'.
DEBUG: Search for kpsewhich in PATH:
DEBUG: Found '/Library/TeX/texbin/kpsewhich'.
DEBUG: TEXMFLOCAL[0]: '/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local'.
DEBUG: Extracting the first element of the list (TEXMFLOCAL[0]):
DEBUG: TEXMFLOCAL[0]='/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local'.
DEBUG: Removing leading "!!" and trailing "//" and set INSTALLROOT:
DEBUG: INSTALLROOT='/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local'.
DEBUG: Environment variable TMPDIR not set.
DEBUG: Environment variable TEMP not set.
DEBUG: Internal variable SYSTMP set to '/tmp'.
DEBUG: Internal variable tmpdir set to '/tmp/getfont-10295'.
DEBUG: Signal handlers installed. Don't expect too much on Windows.
DEBUG: No wget binary found on your system, trying curl.
DEBUG: Running 'curl -O https://www.tug.org/~kotucha/getnonfreefonts/getfont.pl'.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 32681  100 32681    0     0  32681      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01  104k
DEBUG: Running 'perl ./getfont.pl --installroot=/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local --debug --sys --use_curl luximono'.
------------------------------------------------------
Installation directory: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
------------------------------------------------------

===================
Package 'luximono':
===================

Downloading 'http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/LuxiMono.zip'


  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
curl: (55) getpeername() failed with errno 22: Invalid argument
                                                              [download failed]

Download failed.  Please try again.
DEBUG: Info: Execute updmap-sys if exit status is 2.
DEBUG: Exit status of getfont.pl is 0.
DEBUG: Executing Signal Handler:
DEBUG: unlink '/tmp/getfont-10295/getfont.pl'.
DEBUG: rmdir  '/tmp/getfont-10295'.
```

Or this (alternating):

```
DEBUG: getnonfreefonts rev. 2017-06-02.
DEBUG: argv[0]: '/usr/local/bin/getnonfreefonts'
DEBUG: argv[1]: '--sys'
DEBUG: argv[2]: '--debug'
DEBUG: argv[3]: 'luximono'
DEBUG: opt_sys=1
DEBUG: opt_user=0
DEBUG: PATH[0]: '/opt/local/bin'.
DEBUG: PATH[1]: '/opt/local/sbin'.
DEBUG: PATH[2]: '/opt/local/bin'.
DEBUG: PATH[3]: '/opt/local/sbin'.
DEBUG: PATH[4]: '/usr/local/bin'.
DEBUG: PATH[5]: '/usr/bin'.
DEBUG: PATH[6]: '/bin'.
DEBUG: PATH[7]: '/usr/sbin'.
DEBUG: PATH[8]: '/sbin'.
DEBUG: PATH[9]: '/Library/TeX/texbin'.
DEBUG: PATH[10]: '/opt/X11/bin'.
DEBUG: Search for kpsewhich in PATH:
DEBUG: Found '/Library/TeX/texbin/kpsewhich'.
DEBUG: TEXMFLOCAL[0]: '/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local'.
DEBUG: Extracting the first element of the list (TEXMFLOCAL[0]):
DEBUG: TEXMFLOCAL[0]='/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local'.
DEBUG: Removing leading "!!" and trailing "//" and set INSTALLROOT:
DEBUG: INSTALLROOT='/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local'.
DEBUG: Environment variable TMPDIR not set.
DEBUG: Environment variable TEMP not set.
DEBUG: Internal variable SYSTMP set to '/tmp'.
DEBUG: Internal variable tmpdir set to '/tmp/getfont-10337'.
DEBUG: Signal handlers installed. Don't expect too much on Windows.
DEBUG: No wget binary found on your system, trying curl.
DEBUG: Running 'curl -O https://www.tug.org/~kotucha/getnonfreefonts/getfont.pl'.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 32681  100 32681    0     0  32681      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01  125k
DEBUG: Running 'perl ./getfont.pl --installroot=/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local --debug --sys --use_curl luximono'.
------------------------------------------------------
Installation directory: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
------------------------------------------------------

===================
Package 'luximono':
===================

Downloading 'http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/LuxiMono.zip'


  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:01:14 --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to mirrors.ctan.org port 80: Operation timed out
                                                              [download failed]

Download failed.  Please try again.
DEBUG: Info: Execute updmap-sys if exit status is 2.
DEBUG: Exit status of getfont.pl is 0.
DEBUG: Executing Signal Handler:
DEBUG: unlink '/tmp/getfont-10337/getfont.pl'.
DEBUG: rmdir  '/tmp/getfont-10337'.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Indeed, it seems that there are some problems. Be patient and retry tomorrow.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, but also www.ctan.org seems down.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to announced maintenance of the main server for CTAN

Comment: Ok. Fair enough. It is not a question on Tex after all, even though it is one that Tex uses may have.

Comment: As it was scheduled maintenance, the question has become obsolete. Not that it was a bad one.

Comment: But won’t future maintenances cause novices like me to freak out if they don’t follow the ctan maintenance schedule?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was indeed that the servers for ctan.org were down. I retried this morning and managed to install the fonts. Perhaps these errors are too cryptic for me, who don't understand much about curl, but if you get the errors below, it means that the server is likely down.

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to mirrors.ctan.org port 80: Operation timed out
curl: (55) getpeername() failed with errno 22: Invalid argument
```